# Issue with kcfinder creates multiple images from a drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop, kcfinder

Has anyone encountered an issue with using drag-and-drop feature in KCFinder?

This is what I am experiencing, if I drag-and-drop an image to the root folder, it works like a charm.

[image: Drag-and-drop to the root folder]

However, when I drag-and-drop an image to a subfolder, it creates multiple copies of the same image.

[image: Drag-and-drop the the subfolder (icons)]

Any advices will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have solved this issue on your own.

But I'm aware that **kcfinder** [github](https://github.com/sunhater/kcfinder) hasn't been updated in over **2 Years** (I suspect is now "Abandonware")

This being said, I've been maintaining some of the bugs on **kcfinder** including this one (for **ProDev Ltd**), Currently in my fork. I've fixed following bugs with the Image Service with version **3.12**

1. multiple images being uploaded upon drag/drop *EventHandler gets applied each time you change directory, or create new directory. Thus multiple drop handlers result in multiple calls to Upload function*
2. PNG image uploads result with Transparent Backgrounds being repalced with **Black Background** [Relevant Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190624/php-png-images-are-being-uploaded-with-mime-image-jpeg-on-kcfinder-3-12)
3. Sub Directory Symlink Image selection bug fix for Unix *I don't really remember specifics of this one, since I fixed it 8 months ago*

You can find my revision(s) on [prodev kcfinder fork](https://github.com/prodevnz/kcfinder)

Comment: Thanks Killrawr. I haven't used kcfinder for a while now, but it is worth a try with your fixes.

Comment: I only noticed your question the other day, when we came across this issue during our client training, so I thought I'd provide an answer. (if it helped, remember to mark it as answered) Regards

Answer (score 0):

drag/drop EventHandler gets applied each time you change directory, or create new directory. for avoiding this delete or comment on following functions.

1. in `_.expandDir` function remove or comment `_.initDropUpload()`
2. remove or comment `_.initDropUpload()` function in `menus.js` files `_.menuDir` function