# PHP PNG images are being uploaded with mime "image/jpeg" on KCFINDER 3.12

Tags: php, xampp, mime, jquery-file-upload, kcfinder

At this point, I'm very confused for something an image called **this-thing.png** (created as PNG24 out of *photoshop CS5*), gets uploaded to [`kcfinder`](https://kcfinder.sunhater.com/) as `image/jpeg`.

[image]

Analyzed with [TriID](https://web.archive.org/web/20190720212920/http://tridd.com/), shows the image is completely 100% PNG

```
C:\TrID>trid C:\users\michael\downloads\this-thing.png

TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.20 - (C) 2003-15 By M.Pontello
Definitions found:  3790
Analyzing...

Collecting data from file: C:\users\michael\downloads\this-thing.png
100.0% (.PNG) Portable Network Graphics (16000/1)
```

But when the variable data within *$_FILES[(key($_FILES)]['tmp_name']*, reaches **kcfinder\core\class\browser.php** function **moveUploadFile** (as the argument **$file**) ... the mime type from the tmp_name comes up as JPEG and not as PNG.

Modified function, for testing purposes, included code from [getimagesize() not returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464948/getimagesize-not-returning-false-when-it-should)

```
protected function moveUploadFile($file, $dir) {

    $message = $this->checkUploadedFile($file);

    if ($message !== true) {
        if (isset($file['tmp_name']))
            @unlink($file['tmp_name']);
        return "{$file['name']}: $message";
    }

    $filename = $this->normalizeFilename($file['name']);
    $target = "$dir/" . file::getInexistantFilename($filename, $dir);

    echo "<h3>PHP_FILES foreach</h3>";

    foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $key => $value){    
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(getimagesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key]));
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    echo "<h3>TEMP FILE</h3>";
    echo "</strong>file variable</strong>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($file);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "</strong>file.tmp_name</strong>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($file['tmp_name']);
    echo "</pre>";

    $tmp_name_imagesize = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($tmp_name_imagesize);
    echo "</pre>";

    if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) { echo "PNG Supported"; } else { echo "PNG not supported."; }

    // mkaatman - move tmp file to /tmp/ to check its MD5SUM result
    $temporary_file_path = $file['tmp_name'] . ".uploaded";
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $temporary_file_path);

    die();

}
```

Result, during the upload of the file **this-thing.png**, shows that the media type is in fact **JPG** and not **PNG** (this is the part, I can't seem to wrap my head around).

[image]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/kgcgf2af.pyo.png))</sub>

Apparently this file `php92C2.tmp.uploaded` is the uploaded file, to the `/tmp/` directory.

[image]

I have added `.png` to the end of the file, using `Windows Rename`, for the purposes of file analysis.

```
C:\TrID>trid C:\users\michael\downloads\php92C2.tmp.uploaded.png

TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.20 - (C) 2003-15 By M.Pontello
Definitions found:  3790
Analyzing...

Collecting data from file: C:\users\michael\downloads\php92C2.tmp.uploaded.png
 50.0% (.JPG) JFIF JPEG Bitmap (4003/3)
 37.4% (.JPG) JPEG Bitmap (3000/1)
 12.4% (.MP3) MP3 audio (1000/1)
```

But if the image is tested directly through PHP (copy+paste into a directory)

```
<?php

$image_file = "this-thing.png";
$image_file_details = getimagesize($image_file);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($image_file_details);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

The result, reads that the image is in-fact PNG.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 800
    [1] => 300
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="800" height="300"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
```

The form used within **kcfinder/cache/base.js** function **function _.initUploadButton = function()** is your basic, upload form.

```
<div id="upload" style="top:5px;width:77px;height:31px">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="uploadResponse" action="browse.php?type=image&lng=en&opener=ckeditor&act=upload"><input type="file" name="upload[]" onchange="_.uploadFile(this.form)" style="height:31px" multiple="multiple" /><input type="hidden" name="dir" value="" /></form>
</div>
```

Finally some information from KCFINDER.Config from `php`

```
CONFIG.imageDriversPriority

imagick gmagick gd

CONFIG.deniedExts

exe com msi bat php phps phtml php3 php4 cgi pl htaccess htm html

CONFIG.types

Array
(
    [image] => 7z aiff asf avi bmp csv doc fla flv gif gz gzip jpeg jpg mid mov mp3 mp4 mpc mpeg mpg ods odt pdf png ppt pxd qt ram rar rm rmi rmvb rtf sdc sitd swf sxc sxw tar tgz tif tiff txt vsd wav wma wmv xls xml zip
    [images] => 7z aiff asf avi bmp csv doc fla flv gif gz gzip jpeg jpg mid mov mp3 mp4 mpc mpeg mpg ods odt pdf png ppt pxd qt ram rar rm rmi rmvb rtf sdc sitd swf sxc sxw tar tgz tif tiff txt vsd wav wma wmv xls xml zip
    [files] => 7z aiff asf avi bmp csv doc fla flv gif gz gzip jpeg jpg mid mov mp3 mp4 mpc mpeg mpg ods odt pdf png ppt pxd qt ram rar rm rmi rmvb rtf sdc sitd swf sxc sxw tar tgz tif tiff txt vsd wav wma wmv xls xml zip
    [uploads] => 7z aiff asf avi bmp csv doc fla flv gif gz gzip jpeg jpg mid mov mp3 mp4 mpc mpeg mpg ods odt pdf png ppt pxd qt ram rar rm rmi rmvb rtf sdc sitd swf sxc sxw tar tgz tif tiff txt vsd wav wma wmv xls xml zip
    [mimages] => *mime image/gif image/png image/jpeg
)
```

Based on all of this information, I can't seem to figure out why on earth an image being uploaded as PNG, comes back as JPEG.

**EDIT: I have tested, kcfinder using image created from mspaint (this is where it gets confusing)**

The tested PNG image.

[image]

The result (based on the above code).

[image]

```
C:\TrID>trid C:\users\michael\Pictures\breaking-bad.png

TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.20 - (C) 2003-15 By M.Pontello
Definitions found:  3790
Analyzing...

Collecting data from file: C:\users\michael\Pictures\breaking-bad.png
100.0% (.PNG) Portable Network Graphics (16000/1)

C:\TrID>
```

**EDIT: PNG Support (reply for markman)**

```
if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
    echo "PNG Supported";
} else {
    echo "PNG not supported.";
}
```

**EDIT: I've found where the image is being converted from PNG to JPG**

if `checkUploadedFile` is commented out during `moveUploadFile` the file `this-thing.png` comes out as expected PNG....

```
protected function checkUploadedFile(array $aFile=null) {
    $config = &$this->config;
    $file = ($aFile === null) ? $this->file : $aFile;

    if (!is_array($file) || !isset($file['name']))
        return $this->label("Unknown error");

    if (is_array($file['name'])) {
        foreach ($file['name'] as $i => $name) {
            $return = $this->checkUploadedFile(array(
                'name' => $name,
                'tmp_name' => $file['tmp_name'][$i],
                'error' => $file['error'][$i]
            ));
            if ($return !== true)
                return "$name: $return";
        }
        return true;
    }

    $extension = file::getExtension($file['name']);
    $typePatt = strtolower(text::clearWhitespaces($this->types[$this->type]));

    // CHECK FOR UPLOAD ERRORS
    if ($file['error'])
        return
            ($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE) ?
                $this->label("The uploaded file exceeds {size} bytes.",
                    array('size' => ini_get('upload_max_filesize'))) : (
            ($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE) ?
                $this->label("The uploaded file exceeds {size} bytes.",
                    array('size' => $_GET['MAX_FILE_SIZE'])) : (
            ($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL) ?
                $this->label("The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.") : (
            ($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) ?
                $this->label("No file was uploaded.") : (
            ($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR) ?
                $this->label("Missing a temporary folder.") : (
            ($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE) ?
                $this->label("Failed to write file.") :
                $this->label("Unknown error.")
        )))));

    // HIDDEN FILENAMES CHECK
    elseif (substr($file['name'], 0, 1) == ".")
        return $this->label("File name shouldn't begins with '.'");

    // EXTENSION CHECK
    elseif (
        (substr($file['name'], -1) == ".") ||
        !$this->validateExtension($extension, $this->type)
    )
        return $this->label("Denied file extension.");

    // SPECIAL DIRECTORY TYPES CHECK (e.g. *img)
    elseif (preg_match('/^\*([^ ]+)(.*)?$/s', $typePatt, $patt)) {
        list($typePatt, $type, $params) = $patt;
        $class = __NAMESPACE__ . "\\type_$type";
        if (class_exists($class)) {
            $type = new $class();
            $cfg = $config;
            $cfg['filename'] = $file['name'];
            if (strlen($params))
                $cfg['params'] = trim($params);
            $response = $type->checkFile($file['tmp_name'], $cfg);
            if ($response !== true)
                return $this->label($response);
        } else
            return $this->label("Non-existing directory type.");
    }

    // IMAGE RESIZE
    $img = image::factory($this->imageDriver, $file['tmp_name']);
    if (!$img->initError && !$this->imageResize($img, $file['tmp_name']))
        return $this->label("The image is too big and/or cannot be resized.");

    return true;
}
```

Output is `PNG Supported.`

Comment: What does this output? `if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG)  { echo "PNG Supported"; }else{ echo "PNG not supported."; }`

Comment: @mkaatman `PNG Supported`

Comment: If that's the case, your `var_dump($file);` Is it the file you expect? Somehow I suspect you are running against the wrong file or one of your methods is changing the file. What does `pp_array()` do?

Comment: @mkaatman updated the test output, and removed `pp_array()` (which is just a function that uses `pre` and `print_r` to output variables), to reduce confusion.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464948/getimagesize-not-returning-false-when-it-should

Comment: @mkaatman No unfortunately it doesn't help, I've updated the question with results.

Comment: Do `ls -l` or `md5sum` on your tmp file from the command line and see if it matches the file you manually copied over.

Comment: Maybe `getimagesize()` just uses the filename to determine the type, and it's defaulting to JPEG when the temp file doesn't have one.

Comment: @JeremyBanks It doesn't. It reads the mime type from the header of the file. His latest example runs `getimagesize` on `$_FILES` which won't work. He needs to run `move_uploaded_file` first.

Comment: @mkaatman You're right, I went digging for the source [and it says "detect filetype from first bytes"](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/standard/image.c#L1235).

Comment: @JeremyBanks @mkaatman I just have updated the question, using different image... which comes back as `image/png` why is the image `the-thing.png` returning invalid `media type`, even though both images contain consistent `TrID` results? only difference is the transparency between the images.,

Comment: Try downloading http://www.winmd5.com/ and run it against `the-thing.png` vs the `php92C2.tmp.uploaded` or whatever current tmp file and see if it matches.

Comment: @mkaatman I've managed to fix this, thanks for all the help; your first comment was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty confusing issue, I was having. But I have managed to fix it.

Steps involved are as follows

Open the file `kcfinder/core/class/uploader.php` find the function `imageResize`. Then modify the `this.output` code.

Before:

```
    // WRITE TO FILE
    return $img->output("jpeg", array(
        'file' => $file,
        'quality' => $this->config['jpegQuality']
    ));
```

After:

```
    // Check the EXTENSION OF THIS FILE
    if($file && is_string($file) && file_exists($file)) {
        $file_imgsize = @getimagesize($file);
        // Get the EXPECTED EXTENSION from this MIME
        if($file_imgsize && !empty($file_imgsize)) {
            $fileMimeInteger = $file_imgsize[2];
            $outputFileExtension = @image_type_to_extension($fileMimeInteger);
            $outputFileExtension = str_replace('.', '', $outputFileExtension);
        }
    }

    // Force Jpeg
    if(!$outputFileExtension) {
        $outputFileExtension = "jpeg";
    }

    // WRITE TO FILE
    return $img->output($outputFileExtension, array(
        'file' => $file,
        'quality' => $this->config['jpegQuality']
    ));
```

Function:

```
protected function imageResize($image, $file=null) {

        if (!($image instanceof image)) {
            $img = image::factory($this->imageDriver, $image);
            if ($img->initError) return false;
            $file = $image;
        } elseif ($file === null) {
             return false;
        }
        else {
            $img = $image;
        }

        $orientation = 1;
        if (function_exists("exif_read_data")) {
            $orientation = @exif_read_data($file);
            $orientation = isset($orientation['Orientation']) ? $orientation['Orientation'] : 1;
        }

        // IMAGE WILL NOT BE RESIZED WHEN NO WATERMARK AND SIZE IS ACCEPTABLE
        if ((
                !isset($this->config['watermark']['file']) ||
                (!strlen(trim($this->config['watermark']['file'])))
            ) && (
                (
                    !$this->config['maxImageWidth'] &&
                    !$this->config['maxImageHeight']
                ) || (
                    ($img->width <= $this->config['maxImageWidth']) &&
                    ($img->height <= $this->config['maxImageHeight'])
                )
            ) &&
            ($orientation == 1)
        )
            return true;

        // PROPORTIONAL RESIZE
        if ((!$this->config['maxImageWidth'] || !$this->config['maxImageHeight'])) {

            if ($this->config['maxImageWidth'] &&
                ($this->config['maxImageWidth'] < $img->width)
            ) {
                $width = $this->config['maxImageWidth'];
                $height = $img->getPropHeight($width);

            } elseif (
                $this->config['maxImageHeight'] &&
                ($this->config['maxImageHeight'] < $img->height)
            ) {
                $height = $this->config['maxImageHeight'];
                $width = $img->getPropWidth($height);
            }

            if (isset($width) && isset($height) && !$img->resize($width, $height))
                return false;

        // RESIZE TO FIT
        } elseif (
            $this->config['maxImageWidth'] && $this->config['maxImageHeight'] &&
            !$img->resizeFit($this->config['maxImageWidth'], $this->config['maxImageHeight'])
        )
            return false;

        // AUTO FLIP AND ROTATE FROM EXIF
        if ((($orientation == 2) && !$img->flipHorizontal()) ||
            (($orientation == 3) && !$img->rotate(180)) ||
            (($orientation == 4) && !$img->flipVertical()) ||
            (($orientation == 5) && (!$img->flipVertical() || !$img->rotate(90))) ||
            (($orientation == 6) && !$img->rotate(90)) ||
            (($orientation == 7) && (!$img->flipHorizontal() || !$img->rotate(90))) ||
            (($orientation == 8) && !$img->rotate(270))
        )
            return false;
        if (($orientation >= 2) && ($orientation <= 8) && ($this->imageDriver == "imagick"))
            try {
                $img->image->setImageProperty('exif:Orientation', "1");
            } catch (\Exception $e) {}

        // WATERMARK
        if (isset($this->config['watermark']['file']) &&
            is_file($this->config['watermark']['file'])
        ) {
            $left = isset($this->config['watermark']['left'])
                ? $this->config['watermark']['left'] : false;
            $top = isset($this->config['watermark']['top'])
                ? $this->config['watermark']['top'] : false;
            $img->watermark($this->config['watermark']['file'], $left, $top);
        }

        // Check the EXTENSION OF THIS FILE
        if($file && is_string($file) && file_exists($file)) {
            $file_imgsize = @getimagesize($file);
            // Get the EXPECTED EXTENSION from this MIME
            if($file_imgsize && !empty($file_imgsize)) {
                $fileMimeInteger = $file_imgsize[2];
                $outputFileExtension = @image_type_to_extension($fileMimeInteger);
                $outputFileExtension = str_replace('.', '', $outputFileExtension);
            }
        }

        // Force Jpeg
        if(!$outputFileExtension) {
            $outputFileExtension = "jpeg";
        }

        // WRITE TO FILE
        return $img->output($outputFileExtension, array(
            'file' => $file,
            'quality' => $this->config['jpegQuality']
        ));

    }
```

Next, the file `class_image_gd.php` in path `kcfinder/lib/class_image_gd.php` look for the function `output_png` make changes to how the `quality` is worked out (this fixes a PHP related error, with "Compression must be between 0-9").

```
protected function output_png(array $options=array()) {
    $file = isset($options['file']) ? $options['file'] : null;
    $quality = isset($options['quality']) ? $options['quality'] : null;
    $filters = isset($options['filters']) ? $options['filters'] : null;

    if (($file === null) && !headers_sent()) {
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
    }

    // Compression must be between 0-9 - 2/02/2016
    if($quality && is_numeric($quality)) {
        $quality = $quality < 100 ? round(($quality / 100) * 10) : null; 
    } else {
        $quality = null;
    }

    return imagepng($this->image, $file, $quality, $filters);
}
```

Result:

[image]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/q2r5xjr0.b52.png))</sub>

- [kcfinder pull request (for this update)](https://github.com/sunhater/kcfinder/pull/129)
- [github repo with fix](https://github.com/prodevnz/kcfinder)